# How do I print a document from a URL in an e-mail?

Tags: email, printing, url

I have received an e-mail from a potential employer requesting that I print two documents from a URL to take to first day on the job. I have an Apple computer and I do not know what a URL is or how to do it.

Comment: Lol, I hope the new job is not IT support.

Answer (score 2):

First off (super basically), a URL is the location on the internet where web sites/pages, documents, and pretty much everything else is located.  The URL for this question is:

> `https://superuser.com/questions/1272176/how-do-i-print-a-document-in-an-e-mail-in-url`

This is what is seen near the top of your browser in what is usually called the "Address Bar".

> https://www.macobserver.com/imgs/tmo_articles/20120924_safari601search5.jpg?x31150

If the URL your potential employer sent you isn't clickable (meaning you can click the text and it'll take you to your browser to view the page), you can copy and paste it into your browser to make it go there.

Here's a link to what looks like a good resource on how to print something on a Mac.

> http://etc.usf.edu/techease/mac/hardware/how-do-i-print-in-on-the-mac/

I don't use Mac's, so that's more comprehensive than me trying to describe it, but it is essentially going to the "File" menu and selecting "Print", then selecting the printer you want to use.

If you are still confused on what a URL is, all of the text I posted here that starts with "http://" or "https://" is a URL, essentially.  There's more to it, but explaining more would probably just confuse the issue at this point.  The first one I posted is not clickable, while the other 2 are.

I tried to make this as non-technical as possible, but I didn't want to do too much hand-holding, either.  Hopefully this answers the OP's question without annoying or confusing them too much.  :-)